# Simple Diagram Question

Tags: transistors

[image: U10 Relocation]

I am following a trimming tutorial that requires me to replace the U5 transistor with the U10 transistor, and I need some clarification.

1. When it says to cut the trace on the fifth image, is that represented by the point he chipped off at the bottom right of the transistor's traces?
2. Am I supposed to bridge the three bottom pins together in the sixth image?

Comment: #2, they don't tell you to bridge the pins, so it's either rubbish soldering, or a rubbish description

Comment: How should we know? We don't even know what device you're working on...

Comment: Aside from that, I find the red highlighting very unambiguous. I really don't want to shame you if that is the case, but if you can't see what they meant in the 5. picture, you might have a red/green vision problem (which is relatively common).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The images are a little confusing, but I don't think removing the bottom-right pad was the intention or is necessary since C6 is removed and there are no vias.  Colouring the trace red (solid and not showing a cut) also doesn't help, but the meaning is that is the trace you need to cut.  It's a very thin trace so it should be easy and not require the butchering that was done to the board in the image.  Actually the 6th image gives a better view I think of how the trace was cut.
2. I don't know what that IC is so can't comment on whether those pins should be shorted together, but I would assume that they should be based on the photo, even though it's not explicitly stated.